# How to find indices of the leaf nodes X is mapped to in GBRT estimators (Python)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

There's the `apply(X)` function in random forests implemented in sklearn - is there an equivalent for GBRT?

Edited:

```
for estimator in gbrt.estimators_:
    estimator.tree_.apply(X)
```

Gives:

```
File "<pyshell#29>", line 2, in <module>
estimator.tree_.apply(Z)
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'tree_'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apply` method of each individual `estimator.tree_`:

```
for estimator in gbrt.estimators_:
    estimator.tree_.apply(X)
```

If you are doing multi-class classification, there will be one tree per class per stage, so you'd need to do something like:

```
for step in gbrt.estimators_:
    for class_estimator in step:
        class_estimator.tree_.apply(X)
```

Comment: I got an error message doing this...does gbrt have this properties?

Comment: Yes. http://scikit-learn.org/dev/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier What is the error?

Comment: ah. Sorry, gbrt.estimators_ is a numpy array of shape ``(n_estimators, n_classes)``.